# How to Make the scrollview, scroll in specific page when scrolled iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am trying to make the scrollview scroll on specific page programmatically. I also used a pageControl for and and works well. I'm having a problem in Scrolling.

here's how i created my scrollview:

```
contentScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, lengthBarView.frame.size.height + lengthBarView.frame.origin.y, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 143)];
contentScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self addSubview:contentScrollView];
```

here's how I created my Page control:

```
self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init] ;
self.pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(110,385,100,20);
self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
[self.pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

heres my code for the function of my Page control:

```
- (void)changePage:(id)sender {
// update the scroll view to the appropriate page

[secondTabNextView.contentScrollView endEditing: YES];
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = secondTabNextView.contentScrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = secondTabNextView.contentScrollView.frame.size;
[secondTabNextView.contentScrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

and heres my code for the scrollview:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
CGFloat pageWidth = secondTabNextView.contentScrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((secondTabNextView.contentScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

how can I scroll in specific page like dragging a picture from a slide show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it, i only forgot to add paging and scrolling enabled in my scrollview:

```
contentScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, lengthBarView.frame.size.height + lengthBarView.frame.origin.y, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 143)];
contentScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
contentScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
contentScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self addSubview:contentScrollView];
```